# Reversing "Taco" in ASM code makes "ocac" intead of "ocaT" (DOSbox)

Tags: arrays, assembly, dosbox

I am trying to make this code reverse the word "Taco" but I cannot figure out why it keeps getting the last letter wrong in the result. (It keeps outputing "ocac")
I also want the user to write "Taco" as the input which is why I use the INT 21H in the beginning.

I tried using different values like [SI+3], [SI+2] just to understand what is going on but I can't figure it out.

Is it possible to make this work using **LEA?**

```
.model small
.stack 32
.data

VALUE DB 51 DUP('$')

RE LABEL BYTE
MAXLEN DB 50
ACTLEN DB ?
ARR    DB 51 DUP('$')

.code

MAIN proc FAR
;Load Data;
MOV AX, @data
MOV DS, AX

;Get input
MOV AH, 0AH
LEA DX, RE
INT 21H

;Load Pointers to arrays
LEA SI, ARR
LEA BX, VALUE

;Setup CX register for loop.
MOV CX, 0
MOV CL, ACTLEN

AGAIN:
MOV AX, [SI+4]  ;+4 because "Taco" has 4 letters.
MOV [BX], AX    ;Moving character to resulting array
INC BX          ;Move new array to next index
SUB SI, 1       ;Move original array to previous index.
LOOP AGAIN

;Clearing last line
MOV AX, 0601H
MOV BH, 70H
INT 10H

;Printing resulting array on screen
LEA DX, VALUE
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

;Termination
MOV AX, 4C00H
INT 21H
MAIN endp

END MAIN
```

Whoever decides to spend any time answering this, I very much appreciate it!

Comment: have you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: `MOV [BX], AX` is storing *2* bytes, not "a character".  Perhaps you meant to load/store AL, not AX?  Use a debugger to see exactly what goes into memory after you load and store 2 bytes where you meant to copy 1.

Comment: Okay. You guys saved me. I let it slip my mind that AX is going to be 2 bytes. I changed it to AL and now it's finally printing "ocaT"

On top of that I understand now why this was an issue so thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes), AX was dealing with 2 bytes. I switched it to AL so that it is only dealing with 1 byte and finally got "ocaT"

I also changed the [SI+4] to [SI+3] so that it correctly points to the last character of the input array, not after.

```
AGAIN:
MOV AL, [SI+3]  ;changed
MOV [BX], AL    ;changed
INC BX          
SUB SI, 1       
LOOP AGAIN
```

Works great now!